# Быстрое рисование с помощью System.Drawing в Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

Доброго времени суток!
У меня в программе Windows Forms на c# нужно по несколько раз в секунду рисовать большое кол-во квадратиков (или других примитивов, 2D), и постоянно рисовать это на экране. Как это делать наиболее эффективно?

На данный момент рисую все в Bitmap-е, вызываю `this.Refresh()` для того, чтобы запустилось событие формы `Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)` и в нем вывожу этот Bitmap (`e.graphics.DrawImage(bmp,Point.Empty);`). Данный способ хоть все и рисует, и даже частота кадров немалая, но периодически картинка выводится не полностью (часть её просто не выводится).

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно выводить ровное изображение (вернее анимацию) с большой частотой кадров?

Answer (score 1):

Решение сам уже нашел. Если кому надо - проблема решилась выводом картинки в PictureBox.

Comment: Я когда курсач делал, я отрисовывал поле сапёра. Я просто рисовал на сгенерированном bitmapе а потом устанавливал его как BackgroundImage, но правда при отрисовке было видно, как оно меняет фоновую картинку панели, полосы появлялись, потом я натянул повех этого PictureBox и "полосы" пропали. Отрисовывает довольно быстро :-D Не знаю почему я не хотел отрисовывать это на pictureboxe, но это как альтернатива)